# Looking for a simple "WCF+ACS+Windows Azure" walkthrough

Tags: azure, access-control

I just spent the last two hours trying to walk through Microsoft's "Web Services and Identity in Windows Azure Exercise 1: Using Windows Identity Foundation with a WCF Service in Windows Azure" which purports to show how to host a secured WCF service in Azure.

Unfortunately, the walkthrough is ridiculously complicated with a whopping 151 steps.  I've tried to complete the first part of the walkthrough 3 separate times but without any luck.  I'm pretty sure I'm following the instructions exactly as written but there's so much subtlety in there (certificate setup, configuration chaanges, etc.) that it's likely that I'm missing a critical detail.  In either case 151 steps is clearly an order of magnitude too difficult for mere mortals to follow.

Anyway, any help in this rgard would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the BidNow sample. That is a lot less complicated. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/BidNowSample

Also, check out the samples on http://acs.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately I couldn't get the BidNow example to run.  It actually blew up on step 4 of the configuration utility so I didn't get very far.

Comment: As to acs.codeplex.com I couldn't adapt the console-based application to be hosted in a Web Role.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty good article walking through this in the [December 2010 MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490345.aspx) - the fact that it's titled "**Re-Introducing** the Windows Azure AppFabric Access Control Service" says a lot.  You have to "re-introduce" things that no one understood or used when you "introduced" it.  :)